# bootstrapping imputed cem output

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I'm doing coarsened exact matching on an imputed dataset. To validate I do bootstrapping of the results from cem. However I'm unable to get `boot.ci` output to work. I get the error message:

```
Error in bca.ci(boot.out, conf, index[1L], L = L, t = t.o, t0 = t0.o,  : 
  estimated adjustment 'a' is NA
```

The object is there but for some reason I cannot get the bias corrected result.

```
library(boot)
library(cem)
library(Amelia)

am.bo<-function(data,ind) {
  data<-data[ind,]
  a9<-amelia(data,ords=c("gck","gc.m","gc.e","gc.v"),id=c("as2","d30"))
  os<-a9$imputations[1:5]
  os2<-cem(treatment="as2",datalist=os,data=data,drop="bc")
  os3<-att(os2,gck~bc,data=os)
  print(os3,T)->g
  intercept<-g[1,1]
  bac<-g[1,2]
  vec<-c(intercept,bc)
  return(vec)
}

dlply(a4,.(as),function(x) boot(x,am.bo,R=30)) -> bootas_gcadm
lapply(bootas_gcadm,boot.ci)
```

Basically everything is running smoothly, except that I cannot for get the `bca` bootstrap CI.

Comment: I don't know whats the original cause of the problem but I now I get the same problem as you when I have few bootstrap replicates. Seeing that you have R=30, this could be your problem. See https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-February/269006.html